# LESS length() not working, returned as text

Tags: arrays, function, less

I'm trying to get the length of an array with LESS, but I don't know why it is not working.

This code

```
@color_list: black, white, turquoise, green_sea, emerald, nephritis, peter_river, belize_hole, amethyst, wisteria, wet_asphalt, midnight_blue, sun_flower, orange, carrot, pumpkin, alizarin, pomegranate, clouds, silver;

@color_list_length: length(@color_list);

.color-@{color_list_length}{
    content: ' ';
}
```

I understand that should output

> .color-22 {   content: ' '; }

but I'm getting this:

> .color-length(black, white, turquoise, green_sea, emerald, nephritis,
>   peter_river, belize_hole, amethyst, wisteria, wet_asphalt,
>   midnight_blue, sun_flower, orange, carrot, pumpkin, alizarin,
>   pomegranate, clouds, silver, concrete, asbestos) {   content: ""; }

I'm doing something wrong or seems to be an issue with `length()`?

EDIT:

My full code works in [http://lesscss.org/less-preview](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40black%3A%20%23141414%3B%5Cn%40white%3A%20%23ffffff%3B%5Cn%40turquoise%3A%20%231abc9c%3B%5Cn%40green_sea%3A%20%2316a085%3B%5Cn%40emerald%3A%20%232ecc71%3B%5Cn%40nephritis%3A%20%2327ae60%3B%5Cn%40peter_river%3A%20%233498db%3B%5Cn%40belize_hole%3A%20%232980b9%3B%5Cn%40amethyst%3A%20%239b59b6%3B%5Cn%40wisteria%3A%20%238e44ad%3B%5Cn%40wet_asphalt%3A%20%2334495e%3B%5Cn%40midnight_blue%3A%20%232c3e50%3B%5Cn%40sun_flower%3A%20%23f1c40f%3B%5Cn%40orange%3A%20%23f39c12%3B%5Cn%40carrot%3A%20%23e67e22%3B%5Cn%40pumpkin%3A%20%23d35400%3B%5Cn%40alizarin%3A%20%23e74c3c%3B%5Cn%40pomegranate%3A%20%23c0392b%3B%5Cn%40clouds%3A%20%23ecf0f1%3B%5Cn%40silver%3A%20%23bdc3c7%3B%5Cn%40concrete%3A%20%2395a5a6%3B%5Cn%40asbestos%3A%20%237f8c8d%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40color_list%3A%20black%2C%20white%2C%20turquoise%2C%20green_sea%2C%20emerald%2C%20nephritis%2C%20peter_river%2C%20belize_hole%2C%20amethyst%2C%20wisteria%2C%20wet_asphalt%2C%20midnight_blue%2C%20sun_flower%2C%20orange%2C%20carrot%2C%20pumpkin%2C%20alizarin%2C%20pomegranate%2C%20clouds%2C%20silver%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40color_list_length%3A%20length%28%40color_list%29%3B%5Cn%5Cn.generate-color-system%28%40color_list_length%29%3B%5Cn%5Cn.generate-color-system%28%40number%2C%20%40i%3A%201%29%20when%20%28%40i%20%3D%3C%20%40number%29%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%40name%3A%20extract%28%40color_list%2C%20%40i%29%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct.bg-%40%7Bname%7D%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctbackground-color%3A%20%40%40name%3B%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct.generate-color-system%28%40number%2C%20%28%40i%20%2B%201%29%29%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D), but in my project the `length` method are considered like text when compiles. I'm using lessphp.

Comment: Works for me.  http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40color_list%3A%20black%2C%20white%2C%20turquoise%2C%20green_sea%2C%20emerald%2C%20nephritis%2C%20peter_river%2C%20belize_hole%2C%20amethyst%2C%20wisteria%2C%20wet_asphalt%2C%20midnight_blue%2C%20sun_flower%2C%20orange%2C%20carrot%2C%20pumpkin%2C%20alizarin%2C%20pomegranate%2C%20clouds%2C%20silver%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40color_list_length%3A%20length(%40color_list)%3B%5Cn%5Cn.color-%40%7Bcolor_list_length%7D%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%20'%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D

Comment: @SLaks Maybe a compiler problem? I'm using lessphp.

Comment: @GerardReches: [`length()` is not a built-in function in lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#built_in_functions). It does exist in less.js though.

Comment: @Harry Damn, that's it then. Do you know about another way to compile less in server side without access to commands? Post it as an answer and I will select it as the solution :)

Comment: @GerardReches: No, I haven't worked with lessphp and so don't know if there is any option. You may have to look at writing some [custom function](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#custom_functions). I am going to wait a few days to see if anybody else has a better answer. If none comes, I will add this as answer.

Comment: There's [`less.php`](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php) which is much more compliant.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Are you referring to [oyejorge/less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php)? I'm trying it at this moment, hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Yes (it's actually the link in my comment :)

Comment: @seven-phases-max Oh, true, I didn't see the link inside the code markdown :)